# Can someone help figure out how to loop this code?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

```
 document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = totalDistance + ", " + hours + ":" + minutes+", $" + cost;  this is taking all of the different parts of the input and putting it together to make the output
```

Basically the problem i'm having is trying to loop this so that it loops 5 times depending on the user input. I want the user to be able to input new values and click the button and the output to go on the next line of "output1". Currently, every time the user inputs a new set of 5 numbers and clicks the button, the numbers that were present before in "output1" disappear. Any help would be appreciated on getting this to loop 5 times. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are overwriting the output innerhtml every time you run your function.

Replace the last line in your function to append instead:

```
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML += totalDistance + ", " + hours + ":" + minutes+", $" + cost + '<br>';
```

Comment: Ok I did that but it put all of the things together do I have to insert a <br> somewhere to stop this from happening?

Comment: The `<br>` tag means a new line. If you don't put it at the end everything will be write together in the same line.

Comment: Hi @user14664932 I'm glad it worked for you, and if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.